# problems integrating django-autocomplete_light with django-taggit

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

I'm having a hard time integrating them together, when accessing '/autocomplete/CartaoAutocomplete/' I get "Related Field has invalid lookup: icontains". Relevant code:

## models.py

```
class Cartao(models.Model):
    ...
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

## autocomplete_light_registry.py

```
...
autocomplete_light.register(Cartao,
    search_fields=['tags'],
)
```

## forms.py

```
...
class CartaoForm(ModelForm):
    tags = TagField(widget=TagWidget('CartaoAutocomplete'))
```

## admin.py

```
...
class CartaoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = autocomplete_light.modelform_factory(Cartao)
admin.site.register(Cartao, CartaoAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following registers an Autocomplete for "Cartao", which means that it will suggest "Cartao" objects. And what you are trying to do is an Autocomplete to suggest **tags**, which are **Tag** instances. Instead of this:

```
# autocomplete_light_registry.py
autocomplete_light.register(Cartao,
    search_fields=['tags'],
)

# forms.py
class CartaoForm(ModelForm):
    tags = TagField(widget=TagWidget('CartaoAutocomplete'))
```

You should have:

```
# autocomplete_light_registry.py
from taggit.models import Tag
autocomplete_light.register(Tag)

# forms.py
class CartaoForm(ModelForm):
    tags = TagField(widget=TagWidget('TagAutocomplete'))
```

Let me know if this is correct then I will update the documentation.

Comment: That's it, thank you! Now I'm having problems trying to filter the tags based on the request user, without getting a "cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken"? I'm trying something like:

    class TagAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
        def choices_for_request(self):
            choices = super(TagAutocomplete, self).choices_for_request()
            return choices.filter(cartao__user=self.request.user)

Comment: Could you try to format your new problem in a new question please ? Thanks

Comment: sure, there you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319682/cant-make-autocomplete-light-filter-taggit-tags-based-on-request-user

Comment: @jpic Where are `TagField` and `TagWidget` defined here?